# the Greatest Number Among $3^{50} ,4^{40} ,5^{30}$ and $6^{20}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

how to find the Greatest Number Among  $3^{50} ,4^{40} ,5^{30}$ and $6^{20}$   please give a short cut method

Comment: What have you tried? Where do you get stuck? Especially what methods are you supposed to/want to use?

Comment: If you start by taking the $10$th root of each of them, then paper and pencil will suffice.

Comment: For comparing $3^{50}$ and $5^{30}$, see http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1824321/589.

Answer (score 11):

Taking the tenth roots, you need to compare $3^5, 4^4, 5^3, 6^2$  since if $a > b$, $a^{10} > b^{10}$. These are $243, 256, 125, 36$. Thus the greatest is $4^{40}$

Comment: Um, $4^4$ is $256$, not $64$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Back in the older days, when we didn't have super powered calculators, such numbers were general dealt with by taking the log of them.

$$\log(3^{50})=50\log(3)$$

$$\log(4^{40})=40\log(4)$$

$$\log(5^{30})=30\log(5)$$

$$\log(6^{20})=20\log(6)$$

This should be much easier to put into a calculator and compare anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply take logarithm, 
or make exponents same:

$$3^{50}=\left(3^{5}\right)^{{10}};$$

$$4^{40}=\left(4^{4}\right)^{{10}}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$\color\red{4^{40}}=2^{80}=256^{10}>243^{10}=$

$\color\red{3^{50}}=9^{25}>8^{25}=2^{75}>2^{70}=128^{10}>125^{10}=$

$\color\red{5^{30}}>4^{30}=2^{60}=8^{20}>$

$\color\red{6^{20}}$