# Which one is bigger $\sqrt[1023]{1024}$ or $\sqrt[1024]{1023}$

Tags: inequality

Which one is bigger $\sqrt[1023]{1024}$ or $\sqrt[1024]{1023}$

I am really stuck with this one.My friend says that it can be solved by $AM-GM$
but I didn't succes.Any hints?

Comment: which is bigger $\sqrt{3}$ or $\sqrt[3]{2}$

Comment: The second one:).

Comment: Why it is downvoted:(

Comment: @ritwiksinha Cube roots are `\sqrt[3]{2}`: $\sqrt[3]{2}$.

Comment: Same for your question

Comment: maybe because it does not show any effort :)

Comment: I say that I tried AM_GM.

Comment: Why you tried AM or GM ?

Comment: because my friend tell me that it is slovable by that.

Comment: @ritwiksinha: Not "AM or GM", but the [AM-GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means). (No, it's not clear to me how that would be helpful here).

Comment: I thought the question to be http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1612256/showing-that-for-n-geq-3-the-inequality-n1nnn1-holds

Comment: I don't know how I think he is confused.

Comment: Why would you use AM-GM here? When $1<x_1<x_2$ and $0<y_1<y_2$ don't you trivially have
$$x_1^{y_1}<x_1^{y_2}<x_2^{y_2}?$$

Comment: @TahaAkbari also you tagged it with calculus.

Comment: I don' know why my friend saued me.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Raise both numbers to the power of $1023\cdot 1024$ to get $1024^{1024}$ and $1023^{1023}$. Which one looks bigger now?

Alternatively, pick your fravourite from among the two numbers $\sqrt[1023]{1023}$ or $\sqrt[1024]{1024}$, and compare each of the original two numbers to the one you picked.

Comment: @Roby5 Can you compare $\color{red}{\sqrt[1023]{1024}}$ and $\color{blue}{\sqrt[1023]{1023}}$? Can you compare $\color{blue}{\sqrt[1023]{1023}}$ and $\color{red}{\sqrt[1024]{1023}}$? The two blue numbers are the same. What do the two comparisons made say about the two red numbers?

Answer (score 2):

Note that functions $x\mapsto x^n$ and $x\mapsto n^x$ are increasing functions ($x\in\mathbb R_{>0},\ n\in\mathbb N$). Now we have that $$m< n\implies m^m<n^m<n^n\implies (m^m)^{\frac 1 {mn}}<(n^n)^{\frac 1 {mn}}\implies \sqrt[n]m<\sqrt[m]n.$$ Letting $m=2013,\ n=2014$ answers your question.