# Which is larger, $e^\pi$ or $\pi^e$?

Tags: exponential-function, problem-solving

I don't know how to approach this.

I tried expanding $e^{\pi}$ using the power series but that was a dead end since I didn't know what to do with it. I tried estimating if $e \log({\pi})$ was greater or  $\pi$. And I guess $\pi$ is greater but I don't have a rigorous argument.

Comment: An analytical already exists on the site and you can use floor and ceiling functions in that case to conclude $\pi^e<e^{\pi}$

Comment: What is your guess? Do you own a calculator?

Comment: use the function $$f(x)=\frac{x}{\ln(x)}$$

Comment: related: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/517567

Comment: I don't want to solve this using a calculator. I'm guessing e^pi is greater because it's logarithm is probably greater. But, even to compare logarithms I had to resort to sheer numerical calculations.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Consider

$$f(x) = x^\frac{1}{x}$$ You can check that $f$ attains a maximum at $ x = e$ and so $$e^{1/e}\geq \pi^{1/\pi}$$

Can you continue from here?

Comment: even easier to check $g(x)= \log f(x) = \dfrac{\log x}{x}$

Comment: This is true! Thanks for the observation :)