# Is nᵐ>mⁿ if m>n?

Tags: inequality, arithmetic, exponentiation

I remember playing with my calculator when I was young. I really liked big numbers so I'd punch big numbers like $20^{30}$ to see how big it really is.

On such a quest, I did observe that $20^{30}$ is greater than the value of $30^{20}$. In fact, in many cases, I found that $n^m>m^n$ if $m>n$.

Is this a general fact? If so, can it be proved?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/517555/fastest-way-to-check-if-xy-yx

Comment: It is true if $m \gt n \gt e$, but note $1^m \lt m^1$ (for $m \gt 1$) and $2^3 \lt 3^2$ and $2^4=4^2$

Comment: $2^3=8<3^2=9$, so Henry's condition is needed.

Comment: While checking the big numbers you liked, you missed the small ones which make the difference. We have $3 > 2$. But $3^2 = 9$ is not less than $2^3 = 8$. So, your statement is not true for any real value. However, as @Henry says, it will be true for $m > n > e$.

Comment: My bad I guess. In my attempts to verifying for bigger numbers I completely overlooked the smaller ones.

Comment: I prefer to not use MathJax in titles since it would be harder to google for my question.

Comment: @PrittBalagopal Your question is currently a hot network question, and MathJax in the title would disqualify it for that status. I agree that MathJax should only be used in titles only when really needed, not just to make things a little neater.

Comment: Oh, that's great then @JoonasIlmavirta , so unicode superscripts are okay right?

Comment: @PrittBalagopal Apparently so. Special characters should not be an issue for HNQ, but MathJax has been forbidden (it doesn't run on all SE sites, and there must be other technical reasons too). This question is pretty high on the current [HNQ list](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

For a positive integer $m$, consider the function $f(x)=m^x/x^m$. And $g(x)=\ln f(x)=x\ln m-m\ln x$.

Then
$$g'(x)=\ln m-\frac mx$$
which is positive for $x>m/\ln m$. Then $g$ is increasing in $(m/\ln m,\infty)$. For $m>e$ we have $m>m/\ln m$ and $g(x)>0$ for $x>m$. Then, as it has been said in comments,

$$n>m>e\implies m^n>n^m$$

Comment: I guess I didn't properly answer the question and just turned the proposition around. If anyone deserves a tick (or at least +1) then @ajotatxe deserves it.

Answer (score 18):

This is not an answer  I just need to show the graph. I forgot to label axis. Horizontal is $n$ and the other is $m$

Hope you like it

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I already knew the graph. :) Anyway it'll be helpful for other users visiting this question from google. (+1)

Comment: This would benefit from a description of the boundary curves, one being $m=n$ and the other being the other solutions to $\dfrac{\log m}{m} = \dfrac{\log n}{n}$ with $m,n >1$, crossing at $(e,e)$

Comment: @PrittBalagopal: Are you sure you understood what this graph is saying? It shows the regions in which $n^m > m^n$. It answers your question negatively, as there are areas where $m>n$ and yet $m^n>n^m$ (the white area to the left). But if $n>e$ (that's the vertex point where the two shaded areas meet) you have $m>n \Rightarrow n^m>m^n$.

Comment: @MeniRosenfeld Ohh, so that's what it means. Thanks for patching it up

Answer (score 6):

One more attempt:

Consider the function:

$f(x) := \dfrac{x}{\log x}$ , $x \gt e$ (say), is strictly increasing,  since

$f'(x) = \dfrac{\log x - 1}{(\log x)^2} \gt 0$ for $x \gt e$.

$f(x_1) \lt f(x_2)$ for $ x_1 \lt  x_2$.

With  $x_1 = n$ ,  $ x_2= m $,  $  n \lt m $ , $m,n$ positive integers

$\dfrac{n}{\log n} \lt \dfrac{m}{\log(m)}$;

$n \log (m) \lt (m) \log n$;

$\log (m)^n \lt \log (n)^m$ ;

$\exp(\log (m)^n) \lt \exp (\log (n)^m)$;

$m^n \lt n^m$ for $m\gt n.$

Answer (score 3):

You are proposing that $n^m > m^n \iff n > m$. However, there are many examples where this is not entirely true.

If $n = 2 \land m = 3 \implies n^m < m^n : n < m$

If $n = 2 \land m = 4 \implies n^m = m^n : n < m$

And obviously if $n = 1 \land m > 1 \implies n^m < m^n : n < m$

But perhaps what you are trying to say is that:

If $n > m \implies n^m > m^n$ because it seems like $n < m$ in these contradicting examples above. I mean, why do these seem to be the only contradicting examples? With the examples above, we know that $n \neq m \neq 0 \lor 1 \because n^m < m^n$. So moving from $1$ to $2$ where $n = 2$ and $m > 2$, we find a little *shift* in the equality signs.

For the first example, $n^m < m^n$

For the second example, $n^m = m^n$

And it seems that if $m > 2^2 = 4$ then your theory is true where $n^m > m^n$. And it seems like the reason your theory looks true on the condition that $m > 2^2$ is because we must find the first $n^m \lor m^n : n \land m > 1$ (because $1 > 0$ which is obviously $2^2$).

In summary, the theory is not that "if $n^m > m^n$ then $n > m$" but is instead that:

$$\text{if} \qquad n > m \implies n^m > m^n : n \land m \in \mathbb{W}$$

(since $\mathbb{W}$ is the set of all numbers $\ge 0$ aka "Whole Numbers")

Comment: Comment below the things you may not understand here so I can edit the post and tell you whatever it is that you don't understand.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. You clarified a part of my question, so I didn't accept this one. (+1 tho) :)

Comment: OK thanks for letting me know. I figured anyway. But I think it's not that we must find the first $n^m : n \land m > 1$ but we should find the first $n^m > e$, perhaps, according to what everyone else is saying. I appreciate a (+1) tho so thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

In simple terms, for integers you can start with smallest no. i.e. (1,2), (2,3), (2,4).

- $1^2 < 2^1$,
- $2^3 < 3^2$ and
- $2^4 = 4^2$.

In all the above cases $n^m > m^n$ was false for all m>n.
By observing the pattern for all n>=2 and m>4 we have $n^m > m^n$ true. Consider

- (2,5) $\implies$ 32 > 25 or
- (3,4) $\implies$ 81 > 64 or
- (4,100) $\implies$ (1.6 * 10^60) > 100000000 and so on...

So basically even a small number but with large exponent/power is greater than a big number with small exponent as observed above, except for some cases. Bigger exponent matters more than a big base number.

As for the proof part you can take log of $n^m$ and $m^n$.
As the function $\frac{\log x}{x}$ is a decreasing function for x > e($\approx$ 2.718)

$\implies$        $\frac{\log n}{n} > \frac{\log m}{m}$    (for m>n)

So, (as mentioned in above answers also)
m > n > e $\implies$ $n^m > m^n$.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/306553 please use mathjax.

Comment: forgot to add '$'. Added.

Comment: If you think mathjax is complicated, advice: don't read the *whole* thing, and only read what is *necessary* for you. Trust me, I may be a mathy person but I found the mathjax pretty confusing.