# Is this proof about sequence correct?

Tags: solution-verification

I have to prove that $u_n=4^{3n}/3^{4n}$ is a null sequence.
My attempt:
$1/3^{4n}<4^{3n}/3^{4n}<1/3^{n/4}$
Taking limits and by squeeze principle the limit $u_n=4^{3n}/3^{4n}$ tends to 0. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you got your last inequality. Why don't you just write your sequence as $$u_n=\frac{4^{3n}}{3^{4n}}=\left(\frac{4^3}{3^4}\right)^n=\left(\frac{64}{81}\right)^n$$
Since $0<64/81<1$, the sequence tends to $0$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2400996/is-nᵐmⁿ-if-mn/2401274#2401274

Comment: I thought about that but is it accepted as a proof?

Comment: You can do it that way, in the general case, but calculating $3^4$ and $4^3$ is trivial

Comment: Ok. Thank you so much!