# A question about exponential functions: $a^b>b^a$ for $b>a>e$

Tags: inequality, exponential-function, exponentiation

How can we prove that for $b>a>e$ ($e$ being the Euler’s number), $a^b$ is greater than $b^a$?

Comment: You might have a look at [Fastest way to check if $x^y > y^x$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/517555) and [other questions linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/517555).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fastest way to check if $x^y > y^x$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/517555/fastest-way-to-check-if-xy-yx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to prove $x^{1/x}$, or equivalently its logarithm $x^{-1}\ln x$, decreases in $x\ge e$ so that $a^{1/a}>b^{1/b}$. Use the product rule.