# Prove that $(n+3)^2 \le 2^{n+3} , n\in\mathbb{N}$ without induction.

Tags: inequality, alternative-proof

> Prove that: $$(n+3)^2 \le 2^{n+3},\quad n\in\mathbb{N}$$

Please show me how to prove this inequality using a method other than mathematical induction. I was solving some questions based on the principle of mathematical induction and after solving nearly $20$ questions, I noticed that there is always an alternate proof for a statement which I proved by using principle of mathematical induction. So, I was trying to prove the statement given in the title by an alternate method. I found that the inequality can be easily verified from the graph, but I wanted to know if it can be proved in any algebraic way without using graphs.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Inequality is not true for n=0.

Comment: @Extended not everyone includes $0$ in the natural numbers so that might not be a counterexample

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/517555/fastest-way-to-check-if-xy-yx/

Comment: It is time that you started making an effort to format your questions. Math needs to be between $ symbols. Exponents of more than one character need to be enclosed in { }. I have just fixed your title - please look at it to see what I did.

Comment: Incidentally, why do you want to prove the inequality without using induction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at $(x+3)\ln 2-2\ln (x+3)$. It is increasing on $[1,\infty)$. Now can you finish?