# How to compare $\sqrt{2}^{e^\pi}$ and $\pi^{e^\sqrt{2}}$?

Tags: calculus

I know there are nice ways to compare $x^y$, $y^x$ such as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/517555/fastest-way-to-check-if-xy-yx). And for multiple exponential, I think the problem becomes hard. For instance, I want to determine which of $x^{y^z}$ and $z^{y^x}$ is greater without computation. Applying logarithms to both side, we get
\begin{align*}
z\ln y+\ln\ln x,\quad x\ln y+\ln\ln z
\end{align*}
and I can't obtain useful information. Is there any nice way to compare multiple exponential easily?

Comment: What do you mean by compare?Are you familiar with the rate of growth of functions and computing derivatives?

Comment: @Ajay which of $x^{y^z}$, $z^{y^x}$ is greater in general setting.

Comment: Related (not intended to answer this question): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7892/comparing-pie-and-e-pi-without-calculating-them

Comment: What do you mean with "without computation"? Whatever you are going to do to compare these quantities will require some form of computation one way or another.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this will really generalize but here is my attempt-

We have, $ \sqrt{2}^{e^\pi}$ and $ \pi^{e^\sqrt{2}}$. Since we can take the $(e^{\sqrt{2}})$th root on both, this is equivalent to comparing $\sqrt{2}^{e^{\pi-\sqrt{2}}}$ and $\pi$. Further, we can take the $(e^{\pi})$th root on both sides to give $\sqrt{2}^{e^{-\sqrt{2}}}$ and $\pi^{e^{-\pi}}$. (We could do this because $f(x)=x^{\frac{1}{e^\pi}}$ and $f(x)=x^{\frac{1}{e^{\sqrt{2}}}}$ are both increasing functions)

Now consider the function $f(x)=x^{e^{-x}}$. The two final expressions we obtained are just this evaluated at $\sqrt{2}$ and $\pi$. It would be easy to compare now even directly, just by the standard methods of calculus if computationally annoying (thus defeating the entire purpose), but we can alternatively compare $\log_π{f(x)}$ as well, since $g(z)=\log_π(z)$ is an increasing function.