# Without calculator prove that $9^{\sqrt{2}} < \sqrt{2}^9$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality, number-comparison

Without calculator prove that $9^{\sqrt{2}} < \sqrt{2}^9$.

My effort: I tried using the fact $9^{\sqrt{2}}<9^{1.5}=27.$

Also We have $512 <729 \Rightarrow 2^9<27^2 \Rightarrow 2^{\frac{9}{2}}<27 \Rightarrow \sqrt{2}^9=2^{4.5}<27$. But both are below $27$.

Comment: How do you know that $2^{4.5}\lt 27$?

Comment: @JohnDouma its very simple $512<729 \Rightarrow 2^9<27^2$

Comment: Then you should add that to your proof.

Comment: sure thanks for your suggestion

Comment: @Arnaldo yes, so i got stuck

Comment: @lulu as in [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/517555/fastest-way-to-check-if-xy-yx).  But here $1<\sqrt{2}<e<9$ so it is not so easy

Comment: @lulu true but wont that work only for both quantities grater than $e$ or both less than $e$. Here $9>e, \sqrt{2}<e$.

Comment: Absolutely right, I have deleted that comment.

Comment: Using a calculator to cheat a little, we see that $9^{\sqrt2} \approx 22.36$ while $\sqrt{2}^9\approx 22.63$. So it is, for instance, not possible to solve this by wedging an integer between them. If you square them you get $500.04$ versus $512$. Maybe those are easier to compare?

Comment: If we use $\sqrt2<\frac{17}{12}$, then it's enough to show $3^{17}<2^{27}$.

Comment: @lulu What you said is correct, with simple manipulation we can use calculus as shown by two authors below :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you want is a suitable rational upper bound  to $\sqrt{2} \approx 1.4142$ such as $\frac{17}{12} \approx 1.4167$ which you can find for example with continued fractions. As a check, $\left(\frac{17}{12}\right)^2=\frac{289}{144}>2$.

Then you can say $$9^{\sqrt{2}} \lt 9^{17/12}=3^{17/6} = 129140163^{1/6} < 134217728^{1/6} =2^{27/6} =2^{9/2} = \sqrt{2}^9$$

Comment: My solution as well. Don't know why the downvote

Comment: @Milten, Maybe the downvoter didn't like the extraction of a cube root of a nine digit number sans calculator.

Comment: Boohhhh...many times I don't understand!+1

Comment: @PeterPhipps I can see that, though the cube root argument is artificial. It boils down to calculating $3^{17}$ and $2^{37}$, which is tedious for sure, but should be doable in a realistic amount of time (e.g. using exponentiation by squaring or similar).

Comment: Mine as well, +1. I just came up to prove $9^{17}<2^{54}$ ...

Comment: In reality the process was $2^{27}$ to get $134217728$ rather than the other way round, but then reversed to get a line of $<$s and $=$s

Comment: Thank u very much Henry :)

Answer (score 18):

*Remark*: @achille hui posted a similar proof. But we got them  independently.

The desired inequality is written as
$$3^{2\sqrt 2} < (2\sqrt 2)^3$$
or
$$2\sqrt 2\, \ln 3 < 3\ln (2\sqrt 2)$$
or
$$\frac{\ln 3}{3} < \frac{\ln(2\sqrt 2)}{2\sqrt 2}. \tag{1}$$

Let
$$f(x) := \frac{\ln x}{x}.$$
We have
$$f'(x) = \frac{1 - \ln x}{x^2}.$$
Thus, $f'(x) < 0$ on $(\mathrm{e}, \infty)$.

Since $\mathrm{e} < 2\sqrt 2 < 3$, (1) is true.

We are done.

Answer (score 12):

The given inequality can be transformed to various equivalent forms:
$$\begin{align}
9^{\sqrt{2}} \stackrel{?}{<} \sqrt{2}^9 
&\iff (3^2)^{\sqrt{2}} \stackrel{?}{<} \sqrt{2}^{3\times 3} 
\iff 3^{2\sqrt{2}} \stackrel{?}{<} {(2\sqrt{2})}^3\\
&\iff 3^{\frac13} \stackrel{?}{<} {(2\sqrt{2})}^{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}}\end{align}$$

Notice $3 > 2\sqrt{2} \sim 2.828 > e \sim 2.718 $ and the function $x^{\frac1x}$ is strictly decreasing for $x > e$ (standard calculus exercise). The rightmost "inequality" is true
and hence the original "inequality" $9^{\sqrt{2}} < \sqrt{2}^9$ is true.

Comment: (+1). Actually our proofs are similar.

Comment: Nice missed out this simple trick..Tq

Answer (score 4):

Using Henry's approach, but with different estimates. If you know that the first three digits of $\ \sqrt{2}\ $ is $\ 1.41,\ $ then you have: $\ 1.40 < \sqrt{2} < 1.42857\ldots,\ $ i.e.,

$$\ \frac{7}{5} < \sqrt{2} < \frac{10}{7}.$$

So,

$$ \left( 9^{\sqrt{2}} \right)^7 < \left( 9^{ \frac{10}{7}} \right)^7 = 9^{10} = {81}^5 = \left( 80+1 \right)^5 $$

$$ = {80}^5 + 5\times {80}^4 + 10\times {80}^3 + 10\times {80}^2 + 5\times 80 + 1 $$

$$ < {80}^5 + 6 \times {80}^4 = 86 \times {80}^4 < 100 \times{80}^4 $$

$$ =100\times 8^4 \times {10}^4 < 4,100,000,000 = 4.1 \times 10^{9}, $$

whereas

$$ \left(\left(\sqrt{2}\right)^9\right)^7 = \left(\sqrt{2}\right)^{63} = 2^{31}\times \sqrt{2} > 1.4 \times 2^{31} = \frac{7}{2} \times 2^{31} $$

$$ = 7 \times 2^{30} = 7 \times \left( 2^{10} \right)^3 = 7 \times 1024^{3} > 7 \times 1000^3 = 7 \times 10^9. $$

Answer (score 2):

It boils down to the comparison of some powers of $2$ and $3$, if I didn't do any mistake, in the following way: $9^{\sqrt{2}}<\sqrt{2}^9$ if $9<2^{\frac{9}{2\sqrt{2}}}$, by using the fact that $\sqrt{2}<1.415$, if $9<2^{\frac{9}{2\times 1.415}}$ if $9<2^{3.18}$ if $3^{100}<2^{159}$ which is true since:

1. $2^{159}>\frac{1}{2}(1,02\times 10^{3})^{16}>\frac{1.32\times10^{48}}{2}=6,6\times10^{47}$.
2. $3^{100}<(6\times 10^{4})^{10}=3^{10}\times 2^{10}\times 10^{40}<6\times10^{4}\times 1025\times 10^{40}=6,15\times 10^{47}$

Answer (score 2):

$(\sqrt{2})^9 \quad vs.\quad 9^\sqrt{2}\qquad$// square both side

$2^9=512 \quad vs.\quad 
3^{4\sqrt{2}} \;≈\; 3^{5.657} \;<\; 3^5\,3^\frac{2}{3}$

$\displaystyle 3^5\,3^\frac{2}{3} = 243×2×\sqrt[3]{1+\frac{1}{8}} \;<\;486×\left(1+\frac{1}{3×8}\right) = 506.25$

$→ (\sqrt{2})^9 \;>\; 9^\sqrt{2}\qquad$

Comment: It is nice. (+1)