# Which is greater : $66^{70}$ or $70^{66}?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Which is greater : $66^{70}$ or $70^{66}?$

My approach:

Consider $x^y > y^x$.
This is true if and only if $\ln x^y > \ln y^x$,
$y \ln x > x \ln y$
$\frac{\ln x}{\ln y} > \frac{x}{y}$.
Therefore
$66^{70} > 70^{66}$,
since
$\frac{\ln 66}{\ln 70} \approx 0.98615027281$
and
$\frac{66}{70} = \frac{33}{35} \approx 0.942857142857$

But this solution is based on Logarithmic table.Is there any rigorous method?

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Are you aware of differentiation? Maxima? Minima?

Comment: Consider the function $f(x) = x^{66\cdot 70/x}$ and see if you can determine where it is increasing/decreasing

Comment: @YathirajSharma yes sir.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Given $a \gt b \gt 2$ both positive integers, which of $a^b$ and $b^a$ is larger?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/410697/given-ab2-both-positive-integers-which-of-ab-and-ba-is-larger)

Comment: Relevant [video from BlackPenRedPen](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L0XY6llSzyo) on YouTube.